# I just tried to upgrade to Xenial Xerus and now my Ubuntu VM is stuck on this screen?

Tags: upgrade

It's not booting, should I just keep waiting? Nothing is happening except the dots keep blinking red and white.

[image]

Comment: If you hit the ESC key, will it show you a text screen with possible information about what it's doing? Also, please provide more details. Virtuabox? Size of allocated memory and hard disk container size? Cheers, Al

Comment: Pressing ESC doesn't give any more information. Parallels Desktop 11.2.1 running on OS X 10.11.6. 2 CPU, 1GB ram, 64 GB expanding disk.

Comment: See if allocating 2GB RAM to the guest OS makes any difference. How much memory, and how much swap, does the Mac have? Cheers, Al